# Not able to change HTML with jQuery (Local storage)

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I ran into this problem, where I can save the values in the local storage but I'm not able to automatically fill out the contents in HTML. All the necessary values are visible in the Chrome console.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#ChoiceB').change(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('BStored', this.value);
  });
  if (localStorage.getItem('BStored')) {
    $('#ChoiceB').html(localStorage.getItem('BStored'));
  }
  $('#ChoiceK').change(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('KStored', this.value);
  });
  if (localStorage.getItem('KStored')) {
    $('#ChoiceK').html(localStorage.getItem('KStored'));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are reading the *value*, then you need to set the *value* and not the child content.

```
$('#ChoiceB').val(localStorage.getItem('BStored'));
              ^^^
```

Comment: DOH!________________________

Comment: I changed my code but after I reload the page, all the contents of the drop-down list reset (This is the main reason why I work with local storage). I'm still able to see all values (IDs of the contents) in the console after the reload.

Comment: Do you set the `val` when document is ready? Where do you output to the console?

Comment: I have the "$(document).ready(function()" at the top of my whole JS code.

Comment: The different values can be seen in the Chrome console under the tab Application>Local Storage